# Why am I getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined" for line 2 sheet.getRange?

Tags: google-apps-script

This function was working perfectly until this morning and I can't find the reason for the error... I have edited the first line to include the Spreadsheet and it says it is executing normally now but there is no actual post

```
function createMeetingMessage(sheet) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Post") .getRange("B2:D40").getValues(); // Modify this range, if you want to expand it.
  var message = values.reduce(function(s, e) {
    var SlackIDrow, YearsWorkedrow, Congratsrow, _,
    [SlackIDrow, YearsWorkedrow, Congratsrow, _, _, ] = e;
    if (SlackIDrow && YearsWorkedrow && Congratsrow) {
      s += "> *Human* " +"<"+ SlackIDrow +">"+"\n"
     + "> *Years worked as of today* " + YearsWorkedrow + "\n"
     + Congratsrow + "\n"
      +"\n";
    }
    return s;
  }, "> *Today's Workiversaries!*" +"\n");
  return message;
}

function triggerSlackWorkaversaryLog(channel, msg) {
 var slackWebhook = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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";
  var payload = { "channel": channel, "text": msg, "link_names": 1, "username": "Time to Partyyyyyy", "icon_emoji": ":confetti_ball:" };
 var options = { "method": "post", "contentType": "application/json", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "payload": JSON.stringify(payload) };

Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackWebhook, options));
}

function notifySlackChannelofWorkaversaries() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Post");
 if (!sheet.getRange("B2").getValue()) return;
var channel = getChannel();

var msg = createMeetingMessage(sheet);
 triggerSlackWorkaversaryLog(channel, msg);
}

function isTest() {
 return false;
}

function getChannel() {
 if(isTest()) {
 return "intergration_tests";
 } else {
 return "intergration_tests";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to run that function from the script editor you could do this:

```
function testCreateMeetingMessage() {
  Logger.log(CreateMeetingMessage(SpreadsheetApp.getActive());
}
```

Comment: Where would I place this in my data string?

Comment: It's just for testing.  It provides  the function under test with the appropriate parameter.

Comment: I have edited the message above to show my full string. It says it is completing the execution but there is no post being made even though there is data to pull on the 'Post' sheet

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with this line `if (!sheet.getRange("B2").getValue()) return;`  But in any case just single step your way through script with the debugger and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the function you quote but with the function that calls it. The `sheet` parameter must be a `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet` object (rather than a sheet name as text string or something like that.)

You will also get the error you quote if you run the function directly in the script editor.

Comment: I have edited my code and the error message went away but now it is not actually pulling the data to post